# Xcode & Source Control - How to rename branches?

Tags: xcode, version-control, branch, rename

How to rename branches in Source Control in Xcode? I cannot find a way to do it through GUI.

I have tried to search for answers here and on Google. Didn't find an answer regarding Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 12.4 of Xcode (maybe earlier too?) all you need to do is to:

1. Go to Source Control navigator.
2. Select branch
3. Right click on branch and choose **Rename "branch_name"...**

This option was not available when I was asking the question.